# Does somebody know something about Flash-CS5' "multiple copies" bug?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm, generally, complaining, not asking, but if somebody will be able (Adobe isn't) to help - it will be perfect.

I use Flash-CS5 IDE to compose .swc files to import it, then, into FlashDevelop.
Evetyrhing works fine until SOMETIMES. About each 10th "Ctrl+S" (save) click Flash-CS5 duplicates ALL images (loaded .bmp, .jpg, .png... files) and names them like "Copy ..." where "..." is incrementing number. Furhtermore, Flash-CS5 creates duplications of some layers - other layers have duplications of items which put on them. Restoring project's state to previous (not copied) state - is the hell.

This bug is not reproducible but it happens each 2 hours or so - both right after project's opening and after several hours of work. It happens on different machines - I know at least 5 people which told me that they also run into this issue and do not know how to escape it.

Did somebody experienced it? Does somebody know how to handle it?

Comment: This is happening to me all the time now and it's driving me crazy. Have you been able to figure anything out about this? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but the problem persists.

Comment: I posted my project to Adobe and then they chatted with me through e-mail with at least 50 mails asking me for "when and how it happens" but that finished with "we can't help you with it". I reinstalled that too, installed all patches/updated and it didn't helped too. I event tried CS3 and CS4 - no either.

Comment: At my company it was supposed that it happens when computed has a lack of memory, CS5 runs more that 5 minutes and so on... but it's better to believe that it's because of full moon or something else.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens to me also. I have found that if i shut down Flash and restart (without saving again) - when I reopen the fla the duplicated layers/images are not there, though my save has been applied. Don't save twice or it will keep the duplicates as well.

Answer (score 1):

Been working with flash for a while, just running into this problem now in CS5, the file may have been down-saved from 5.5 at some point.

This problem is also mentioned [here](http://dustytome.net/moot/2011/01/cs5-bitmap-duplication-bug/).

Some details about our project:

- we import for runtime sharing from 1 other FLA.
- we have hundreds of bitmaps, and hundreds of movieclips.
- we have many assets export for actionscript.

We have seen the problem both on SAVE and when regaining focus on the window.
the duplication started with just bitmaps, but has spread to other assets as well, even putting them on top of the originals on the stage.

Several machines have worked on this file, only the slowest machine (2GB ram XP) sees the problem (so far)
the machines that do not see the problem are XP also which caps the RAM to 3GB.

But we have larger FLA's that the slow machine will just corrupt or crash w/o duplication it's odd that we didn't see duplication in those FLA's months ago.

We are going to try:

1. reinstall flash
2. get a better machine. (more RAM)

Until then to try to monitor the problem and to know when to revert the file and try again, we are keeping track of the item count on the library.